# Astroquery: AttributeError("'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'")

Tags: python, astropy

I would like to run the NED query of the [astroquery package](https://github.com/adrn/astroquery/blob/master/docs/ned/ned.rst).

```
from astroquery.ned import Ned
result_table = Ned.query_object("NGC 224")
```

this is given by the example in the Documentary.

I got the following issue:

```
TableParseError: Failed to parse NED result! The raw response can be found in
self.response, and the error in self.table_parse_error.
```

In self.table_parse_error I find:

```
 AttributeError("'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'")
```

I have no idea what has gone wrong.

Here are my versions:

```
Python  3.4.1 (default, May 19 2014, 17:23:49) [GCC 4.9.0 20140507 (prerelease)]
SciPy   0.14.0
Cython  0.20.1
OS      posix [linux]
Numpy   1.8.1
IPython 2.1.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was raised as an issue on astroquery and is a confirmed bug:
https://github.com/astropy/astroquery/pull/343

it should be fixed shortly